# $(\lim_{b\to \infty}\int_{t}^{b} f(s)ds)'=\lim_{b\to \infty} (\int_{t}^{b}f(s)ds)'$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

What minimum condition must be met so that $(\lim_{b\to \infty}\int_{t}^{b} f(s)ds)'=\lim_{b\to \infty} (\int_{t}^{b}f(s)ds)'$ with $()'=\frac{d}{dt}$?

Comment: This looks like a trick question of some kind; do you know the fundamental theorem of calculus?